# Add document click listener after a button is clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a jQuery click listener AFTER a certain button on page is clicked. After the button is clicked, you click anywhere on the page and the script will run. Problem is the handler runs right after you click on the button, and does not wait for a "body" click. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
    <button data-stat="off" onclick="handler(this);">Click here</button>

</body>
    <script>
    function handler(btn){
        if ($(btn).attr("data-stat")=="on"){
            $(btn).attr("data-stat", "off");
            console.log("A");
        }
        else {
            $(btn).attr("data-stat", "on");
            $(document).on("click", function (event) {
                console.log("body clicked!");
                $(this).unbind();
            });
        }     
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does "anywhere on the page" include a *second* click on the original button? (Regarding the `.unbind()`, you can just use `.one()` instead of `.on()` and the unbinding will happen automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the timeout to append the listener after the current event loop:

```
function handler(btn){
    if ($(btn).attr("data-stat")=="on"){
        $(btn).attr("data-stat", "off");
        console.log("A");
    }
    else {
        $(btn).attr("data-stat", "on");

        // add after 1 ms
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(document).on("click", function (event) {
                console.log("body clicked!");
                $(this).unbind();
            });
        }, 1);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event is bubbling up the DOM so that when you attach a new event handler to a parent element it will call straight away. There is a method called `stopPropagation()` which will stop the event bubbling up. Just add it in your `handler()` method.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
    <button data-stat="off" onclick="handler(this, event);">Click here</button>

</body>
    <script>
    function handler(btn, ev){
        ev.stopPropagation();

        if ($(btn).attr("data-stat")=="on"){
            $(btn).attr("data-stat", "off");
            console.log("A");
        }
        else {
            $(btn).attr("data-stat", "on");
            $(document).on("click", function (event) {
                console.log("body clicked!");
                $(this).unbind();
            });
        }     
    }
    </script>
</html>
```